# How do I adjust bins to endpoint instead of midpoint in proc sgpanel

Tags: sas

I've got a panel of three histograms and I've been able to figure out how to tweak all of the formatting except for one thing:  getting the ticks to be the endpoints for the bins, instead of the midpoints.

I know that in 'proc univariate,' one can use an 'endpoints=' option in the histogram statement.

However, I cannot find a similar statement in the documentation for 'proc sgpanel'

Here is my code:

```
ods graphics on;
title "Baseline";
proc sgpanel data=baseline;
  panelby scrp_cohort2 / rows=3 layout=rowlattice;
  histogram pt_eq5d3l_health_state / boundary=lower group=scrp_cohort2;
  where time=0;
  colaxis min=0 max=100 grid values=(0 to 100 by 10);
run;
ods graphics off;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you're trying to manipualte a histogram, which is a chart that is not a discrete-values chart, even though it *looks* like it is such a chart.  For example, `VBAR` would offer a `discreteoffset` option that would let you do exactly what you ask.

However, a histogram is a chart that graphs *not* discrete values on an x/y axis, just in a particular way that ends up looking sort of like a bar chart.  So it won't let you move the labels around, because they're *not* just labels - they're fixed positions on the axis, which the histogram is collapsing points around.

Unfortunately, the `endpoints` option isn't available for PROC SGPANEL, which of course would be how you'd ideally solve this issue.  You have a couple of options for what would work, depending on what you want to do exactly and what your data look like.

First, you can simply summarize your data using `proc univariate` or whatever works best, and then use `vbar` to graph the (now discrete) data.  You can get a histogram dataset out of `proc univariate` easily enough (with `ODS OUTPUT` or `OUTHISTOGRAM=` option) with `by` statement for your group/panel values, and then you can graph that with `VBAR` in `SGPANEL`.

Second, you can make some adjustments to how things are done in `SGPANEL`, which might be enough for your needs.  Look at the following graph, using Richard's example data.

```
proc sgpanel data=have;
  panelby panel / rows=3 layout=rowlattice;
  histogram status / boundary=lower group=group binstart=-5 binwidth=10;
  where time=0;
  colaxis min=0 max=100 grid values=(0 to 100 by 10) ;
run;
```

What it does is start the bins at -5, instead of at 0, but the `colaxis` is still starting at zero.  That's now accurately doing what you want, I think - except that 0 itself ends up in the -5 bar, which you might not want.  The bins are now centered at 5/15/25/35/etc., which is hopefully what you do want.  If you do have 0 in your data, you may be able to use options to move where 0 is bucketed (but it would affect all of the other exact endpoints also).

This is what that looks like with the 0's removed.  If there are actual 0's, then you would have a bar to the left of the plot area, though.

[image: Histogram with things aligned properly]

Here is the same thing but with 0's in it, which you'll note means a bar to the left of 0.

[image: Histogram with 0 bar on the left of 0]

This is a similar plot but with 0's allowed, and with boundary=upper which moves all of the exactly-on-bin-boundaries to the upper bin (so 0 goes to the 0-10 bin).  Note the other changes - and there is now a 100-110 bar which contains the 100 values.

[image: Histogram with 0 now in the 0-10 bar]

Code for the latter chart (earlier chart is same but `boundary=lower`):

```
title "Baseline";
proc sgpanel data=have;
  panelby panel / rows=3 layout=rowlattice;
  histogram status / boundary=lower group=group binstart=-5 binwidth=10 boundary=upper;
  where time=0;
  colaxis min=0 max=100 grid values=(0 to 100 by 10) ;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify a `colaxis` `offsetmin` and `offsetmax` that are 1/2 the bin width (as fraction).

Example:

Three `SGPANEL` runs to compare and contrast.  The final one is the one you want.

```
data have;
  call streaminit(2021);

  do panel = 1 to 3;
    do _n_ = 1 to 100 + rand('integer',50);
      id + 1;
      group = rand('integer',3);
      do time = 0 to 10;
        status = rand('integer',0,100);
        output;
      end; 
    end;
  end;

  stop;
run;


ods html file='gfx.html';

ods graphics on/ height=400 width=500;
title "Baseline";
proc sgpanel data=have;
  panelby panel / rows=3 layout=rowlattice;
  histogram status / boundary=lower group=group;
  where time=0;
run;

proc sgpanel data=have;
  panelby panel / rows=3 layout=rowlattice;
  histogram status / boundary=lower group=group;
  where time=0;
  colaxis min=0 max=100 grid values=(0 to 100 by 20);
run;


proc sgpanel data=have;
  panelby panel / rows=3 layout=rowlattice;
  histogram status / boundary=lower group=group;
  where time=0;
  colaxis grid values=(0 to 100 by 10)
    offsetmin=0.05 
    offsetmax=0.05
  ;
run;

ods graphics off;
ods html close;
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What if you write `colaxis min=-5 max=105 grid values=(0 to 100 by 10);`?

Comment: IIRC, my experience was that the `colaxis` range was based on `values=`, taking precedence over `min` and `max`

Comment: I'm sorry but, in your answer, all three plots still have the tick marks as the midpoints of the bins.  I'm looking for tick marks like in the third plot, but the left edge of the first bin needs to align with 0, and the right edge aligned with 10, all the way so that the last bin covers 90 to 100, and the right edge of the bin aligns with 100,

Also, I tried the min=-5 and max=105 and that didn't work either.

Comment: Maybe you can hand-draw the desired axis and add that to the question.  If the tick point visualization is from something else such as Excel, post a screenshot from that